# SQL "null values" for ORDER BY and equality?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a generic query that receives the value of the ORDER BY query as a parameter. However, it is sometimes the case that no special ordering needs to be done. Which value could I use to make this happen? Or is that not possible?

I also have the '=' value as a parameter, and I would like to write 'WHERE a_column = ..." where '...' denotes no constraints (i.e. equal to "I don't care what"). I however do not know which value I can use for that.

Could someone help me?

I tried ORDER BY "", but that changed the ordering too.

Comment: Add debugging details to your post, including sample input table(s) and corresponding expected output.

Comment: `I tried ORDER BY "", but that changed the ordering too.` ... that is what `ORDER BY` is supposed to do.

Comment: Where are you trying to pass it a parameter from? SQL or some other programming language?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any specific order, simply use

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

and it will select all and order by id.

You need random ordering? If that's the case, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND();
```

If you really want to use WHERE just to check how it works, you can try checking if

```
a_column = '%rand_string%'
```

or integer or something, depending on the column data type